# Unit testing with long inputs

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTestMethod()
{
    string input = "some looooong input...";

    var proc = new Processor()
    string result = proc.DoSomething(input);

    Assert.Equals("good", result);
}
```

If I'm writing a unit test and I have an input that is extremely long (such as EDI transactions), should I just paste that into my test method as a long string?

Others have suggested I should paste that long string into a file and treat that file as an embedded resource in my test project.  If I do something like that and I need different inputs for each of my tests, I could see a lot of files piling up and becoming hard to maintain.

Are there any best practices surrounding this?  Should I just continue pasting these long strings into my test methods?

Answer (score 7):

I always put long test strings into resources, and maintain consistent naming between tests and their resources to keep the mapping easy. I use the same name for the resource and the test. When I need several resources for a test, I add a suffix `1`, `2`, `3`, and so on.

Comment: this will also let Intellisense give you a peek at the resource - cool

Answer (score 4):

You can use a different string constructor to create a very long string of repeated characters, such as this:

```
string input = new string('x', 1024 * 1024 / 2);
```

That approach gives a much more elegant way of creating long strings withing having to paste long strings into your tests.

Comment: Well, million x's doesn't look to me like an EDI transaction :)

Comment: True, but then neither does "some looooong input..."  It could be that you'd need to make the first part of the string contain valid header info, but then fill the bulk of the string with a method such as this.  This approach may not work depending on what you need to test, but if you just need something extremely long it does provide a good approach for creating a long string.

Answer (score 3):

I was testing some regexp which against file. What I did is I copy pasted the content of the file into the test class as a normal property but I used the #region tags to hide it. I don't need to see 200 lines of text every time I open that test class. This is also one of the few cases where I find the #region tag useful.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing `Processor`'s code, as I see it, `Processor` should have simple, fast, unit tests covering its inner workings, while tests like `SomeTestMethod` should be regarded as **Integration tests**.

As such, I would store all my test data in an XML file, and load it into the test, running the same test for every input (If you wish to test serious amounts of data - you can use a database). There is no need in writing separate tests for each input.

A very clean and elegant approach on how this is done in MSTest is described [here](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/01/18/How-to-simulate-RowTest-with-MS-Test.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If its something quick which I don't care about I drop it in the code. Since I'm more than likely testing an concept.

If its code your going to keep like tests or production code then use a resource file either as an embedded resource or using a resx file, which ever you are more comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an "opinionated" answer since I've never seen any best practice regarding this;

I work with EDI files and our test cases are usually self contained with pasted test data just as you do it, in our case as constants defined outside the test itself as to not clutter up the actual test code.

We found that the handling of external files is error prone in itself.